# Sqoop - The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I've tried to import DBMS (windows machine) into HDFS (Linux) using Sqoop.

The command I used is:

```
 sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://ip-dbms/db-name" --table table_name --username username -P --target-dir imported_sql
```

After I run the command and input the password, it soon gives the error:

```
The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone.
```

I checked my `HDFS` machine's timezone and it is `Asia/******`

How to solve it?

Comment: Did you mean `Asia/Singapore`?  Also, what does `tzutil /g` on your Windows machine return?

Comment: `tzutil /g` returns `Singapore Standard Time`